# Use Monaca Version in ios app

Tags: monaca

I am using Monaca Cloud IDE to build an ios (and android) app. In the App Build Settings > App Settings there is a required field of Version Number. I would like to display this number in my apps splash screen and an About screen in the app. Is this number accessible as a variable from within the app? If so how would I reference it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this [cordova-plugin-app-version](https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version) plugin might help you to achieve what you want. It reads the version of your app from the target build settings. Hope this helps!